# Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

Trying to use nuclide with atom but I cannot get the debugger to work. I have nuclide installed (v0.243.0). Running on Mac and followed the setup instructions in the docs. I run the RN packager within Nuclide, start the debugger and then run 'react-native run-ios' from terminal and lastly enable chrome debugging.But I cannot find find nuclide command 'Nuclide React Native: Start Debugging'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNV9U.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React Native debugger support was dropped by  [[fccd95d]](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/commit/fccd95d310d021ad67a6e524066bd9ab91e0e3ca)

Comment: 多谢指点，现在有什么好办法可以用来Debug吗？

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge. Spent too long on this.